# Find the Matrix M of the linear Transformation T: R...

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the matrix $M$ of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow
>  \mathbb R^2$ given by
>
> $T\begin{bmatrix}
> x_1\\
> x_2\\
> x_3\\
> \end{bmatrix}$ = $ \begin{bmatrix}
> -3x_1 + x_2 -5x_3\\
> 8x_1 -7x_3\\
> \end{bmatrix}$

How exactly do you do this?
Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a theorem that tells you that in order to find the matrix of the linear transformation, you should apply $T$ to the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However, if you just want to know how to do it, in simple cases like this one, simply write down the matrix with the same coefficients of the linear tranformation, i.e.

$\begin{pmatrix}
  -3 & 1 & -5 \\
  8 & 0 & -7 
 \end{pmatrix}$

This happens because if you apply $T$ to the standard basic vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, you would get exactly $(-3,8), (1,0), (-5,-7)$.

As an example$\begin{pmatrix}
  -3x_1 & 1x_2 & -5x_3 \\
  8x_1 & 0x_2 & -7x_3 
 \end{pmatrix}$  now use these values for the $x's$ $(1,0,0)$and you'll get $(-3,8)$